# Does chaining prefetch_related fetch all sub-queries?

Tags: python, django

Take this for example:

`user = User.objects.prefetch_related("foo__bar__baz").get(id=id)`

In this scenario, do I not need to do:

`user = User.objects.prefetch_related("foo__bar").get(id=id)` if I want to access values on `bar`, or if they are mixed between `select_related` and `prefetch_related` due to some being OneToOne and others being FK like this below?

`user = User.objects.prefetch_related("foo__bar__baz").select_related("foo_bar_baz_qux").get(id=id)`

Or would skipping the prefetch and only using select be sufficient?

`user = User.objects.select_related("foo_bar_baz_qux").get(id=id)`